# Convert textbox entry into an integer

Tags: string, integer

I promise I have checked answers that might be relevant to this, but none of them have worked.

I want a number entry into a text box to be turned into an integer variable.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim intsessionlength as integer

timeinputbox.text = intsessionlength
```

When I hover over timeinputbox.text I see the value that I entered into the text box, but when I hover over intesessionlength I get a zero.

I also tried:

```
Convert.ToInt32(timeinputbox.text)
```

Thank you!

Comment: language ? compiler ? versions ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017.